# Jquery ui datepicker previous button not working

Tags: html, jquery-ui, css

The jQuery UI datepicker previous button is not working properly, and even some days it is not clickable when used with `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;`

Otherwise, when jQuery UI datepicker is normally used it works fine.

```
<head>
<title>Check Windows</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />              
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
 });
</script>
<style>
 * 
 { 
 box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  }


 .frame 
  {   
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
   float:left;
  }

  .square:hover .flipper

  {
   -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
   -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }


 .flipper 
{
 -webkit-transition:all 0.6s;
 -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
}

 .front, .back 
  {

   height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
 position:absolute;
 }

 .back

  {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
 -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
 }


 .f1
 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
 background-color:FF1D77;
font:normal 32px   Comic Sans MS;
text-align:center;
  }

 .b1
 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
 }
 .ui-datepicker
 {  
 height: 300px;
width: 400px;
 }




 </style>



  <body>

   <div class="frame square" 
        style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left:0px;margin:15px;"> 
    <div class="flipper">
    <div class="front f1">
   <div><br><br>Mouseover to see the Calendar</div>
   </div>
      <div class="back b1">
     <div id="datepicker"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seems working fine.

check the fiddle that I have created to use your HTML mentioned above.

jsfiddle.net/VQwJN/

If you are facing any problem them please elaborate.

Comment: 1. previous month button is not working.
2. Dates of sunday monday tuesday can't be selected